# Oracle Pivot Query Compare Columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am rusty on my Oracle skills anyways I have the following Oracle Query that pivots and give me what I need however I need to compare the last two columns. Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM (select * 
FROM (select TO_ENTITY_ID, END_DATE_DAY_ID, EASSIGNMENT_ID from ENTITY_eassignment WHERE TO_ENTITY_ID IN  (11466248, 993051,993037))
PIVOT (MAX(END_DATE_DAY_ID) AS t FOR (EASSIGNMENT_ID) in (1, 1002)));
```

This ultimately returns 3 rows and 3 columns

```
TO_ENTITY_ID    1_T     1002_T     
993037          29220   29220      
11466248        29220   16126      
993051          15255   16004
```

What I need to do is add a 4th column here that compares the last two columns if they are the same value then the 4th column should be true/false.

```
TO_ENTITY_ID    1_T     1002_T  SAME_VALUE     
993037          29220   29220   TRUE
11466248        29220   16126   FALSE   
993051          15255   16004   FALSE
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(CASE WHEN "1_T" = "1002_T"
      THEN 'TRUE'
      ELSE 'FALSE'
  END)
```

in an outer query should work.  That is

```
SELECT to_entity_id,
       "1_T",
       "1002_T",
       (CASE WHEN "1_T" = "1002_T"
             THEN 'TRUE'
             ELSE 'FALSE'
         END)
  FROM( <<your existing query>> )
```

If you want to filter

```
SELECT to_entity_id,
       "1_T",
       "1002_T",
       (CASE WHEN "1_T" = "1002_T"
             THEN 'TRUE'
             ELSE 'FALSE'
         END)
  FROM( <<your existing query>> )
 WHERE "1_T" = "1002_T" -- (or !=)
```

Comment: Justin, where would I put this??

Comment: @kevinc - In an outer query.  I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm!!

Comment: Justin, If I wanted to add a where to the query at the end to filter by true/false how could I do that?

Comment: @kevinc - Add a `WHERE` clause.  It doesn't really make sense to filter based on a `CASE` statement that is this simple, just compare the `"1_T"` and `"1002_T"` values in your `WHERE` clause.  Added an example